# Merge Multiple html files into one

Tags: html, bash

With the help of you guys, i have written a code to get output of my program in html file.

but now the problem is for each server i am getting a separate html file
e.g. 
10.106.86.00_FinalData.html,10.106.86.01_FinalData.html ...

Below is the code which is generating the html file for each server

```
Dell_Data_Status_3=`cat /home/${svr}_Data_Status_3.csv`
var=$(printf "%s\n" "${Dell_Data_Status_3[@]}" |
awk -F, '
$3==3{
    f2=$2=f2 (f2==""?"":",") $2
    out=$0
}
END { print out }')
#echo $var
ServerName=`echo "$var" | awk -F " " {'print $1'}`
Index=`echo "$var" | awk -F " " {'print $2'}`
Status=`echo "$var" | awk -F " " {'print $3'}`



echo "<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ServerName</th>
    <th>Index</th>
    <th>Status</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>$ServerName</td>
    <td>$Index</td>
    <td bgcolor=#00FF00>OK</td>
  </tr>

</table>

</body>
</html>

" >> /home/${svr}_FinalData.html
```

Need to merge these all file in to one. 
please need your help in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have generated files and you want to merge the content and keep the header you can make nother program, merger.sh:

```
echo "<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>" > /home/MergedFinalData.html

for $file in $(ls /home/*_FinalData.html) ; do
    head -n23 $file | tail -n13 >> /home/MergedFinalData.html ;    
done

echo "</body>
</html>" >> /home/MergedFinalData.html
```

Comment: Thanks..It is merging the files. But how to avoid multiple headers...? Each file having same header.